# id: user: no such user

Tags: centos7, kerberos, pam, sssd

I'm using Centos 7 to authenticate locally Active directory users using kerberos. I joined the realm with the Administrator and i can login/ssh through it/with it, **nslookup** working fine, and  **adcli info** is working. When i create another user called test and try to login through Centos i get the following :
 `id: test: no such user`

**getent passwd test** doesn't return anything

Here are my configuration files:

**sssd.conf**

```
domains = gio.server
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/gio.server]
ad_domain = gio.server
krb5_realm = GIO.SERVER
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = ad
```

Here is the **krb5.conf**

```
# Configuration snippets may be placed in this directory as well
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

includedir /var/lib/sss/pubconf/krb5.include.d/
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default = GIO.SERVER
 dns_lookup_realm = true
 dns_lookup_kdc = true
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 pkinit_anchors = FILE:/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
# default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

 default_realm = GIO.SERVER
[realms]
 GIO.SERVER = {
kdc = gio.server:88
default_domain = gio.server
#  kdc = kerberos.example.com
#  admin_server = kerberos.example.com
 }


[domain_realm]
# .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
# example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
 .gio.server = GIO.SERVER
 gio.server = GIO.SERVER
```

However when i was troubleshooting using **sssctl user-checks test** it returned the following error:

```
user: test
action: acct
service: system-auth

sss_getpwnam_r failed with [0].
User name lookup with [test] failed.
Unable to get user objectInfoPipe User lookup with [test] failed.
testing pam_acct_mgmt

pam_acct_mgmt: User not known to the underlying authentication module

PAM Environment:
 - no env -
```

Please if something is missing let me know.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is a lack of read permissions for specific properties that the computer account needs for the user accounts in AD.

When a user is added to Domain Admins, permission inheritance gets disabled and certain permissions are explicitly granted to Authenticated Users. This allows the server to pull the necessary properties to authenticate admins, but not normal users.

To correct the issue, grant Authenticated Users or a specifically created security group the "List contents", "Read all properties", and "Read permissions" permissions on the root of the domain applying to "Descendant User objects".